# Add tooltip to column name in a subgrid in Dynamics 365

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-365

I want to add a tooltip to the column name in a subgrid. For Example, if I am hovering over Category in the below subgrid, I can see the text "Sort by Category". Instead, I want to see some other text.

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a product limitation as of today. The tooltip is generated by platform in a predefined fashion & we don’t have control to customize/configure it in any supported way.

The entity form will show the [description as tooltip](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2014/04/customizable-tooltips-in-crm-2013/) against each attribute, You can add an idea in [MS portal](https://experience.dynamics.com/ideas/) for subgrid header tooltip configuration.